# Passing data to currentNode pointer from a class

Tags: c++, pointers

I am currently having trouble with outputting from my program correctly. The currentNode pointer is empty, and I am unsure how to get it to not be empty. This program deals with linked lists, and I have tried using getters to no avail (I get a segmentation fault when I try). The program is supposed to take state parks, insert them into a linked list, search for pertinent data from the state parks, and output the summary to a file. All I get is output statements in the file, with no data where it should be. Here is all pertinent code to the program:

parkLL.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct ParksNode;
typedef ParksNode* ParksPtr;
struct ParksNode
{
    string parkName;
    string parkLocation;
    string parkOpeningYear;
    string parkDescription;
    int noTimesReferenced;
    ParksPtr parkLink;
};




class Parks
{
public:
    Parks();
    ~Parks();
    void Delete(string pName);
    int GetLength() const;
    ParksNode GetNextPark();
    bool HasNext() const;
    void Insert(string& pName, string& pLocation, string& pOpeningYear, 
string& pDescription, int& numberTimesReferenced);
    bool IsEmpty() const;
    bool IsFull() const;
    bool IsThere(string pName) const;

private:
ParksNode* parkDataPtr; //Points to the first node in the list
int length;
ParksNode* parkCurrentPos; //Points to the current position in the list
ParksNode* parkLastPtr; //Point to the last node in the list

};
```

parkLL.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include "parkLL.h"
using namespace std;



Parks::Parks()
//The parkDataPtr will be set to NULL
{
    parkDataPtr = NULL;
    parkCurrentPos = parkDataPtr;
    length = 0;
}

Parks::~Parks()
//The destructor for the Parks Linked List class
{
    ParksPtr parkTempPtr;
    ParksPtr parkCurrPtr = parkDataPtr;
    while(parkCurrPtr != NULL)
    {
        parkTempPtr = parkCurrPtr;
        parkCurrPtr = parkCurrPtr->parkLink;
        delete parkTempPtr;
    }
}

void Parks::Delete(string pName)
//The delete method for the Parks Linked List class
{
    ParksPtr parkPrevPtr = NULL; //The trailing pointer for the list
    ParksPtr parkCurrPtr = parkDataPtr; //The loop control pointer

    while(parkCurrPtr != NULL && parkCurrPtr->parkName != pName && 
parkCurrPtr->parkName < pName)
    {
        parkPrevPtr = parkCurrPtr;
        parkCurrPtr = parkCurrPtr->parkLink;
    }
    if(parkCurrPtr != NULL && parkCurrPtr->parkName == pName) //the item has 
been found
    {
        if(parkCurrPtr == parkDataPtr)
        {
            parkDataPtr = parkCurrPtr->parkLink;
        }
        else
        {
            parkPrevPtr->parkLink = parkCurrPtr->parkLink;
        }
        if(parkCurrPtr == parkLastPtr)
        {
            parkLastPtr = parkPrevPtr;
        }
        delete parkCurrPtr;
        length--;
    }
}

int Parks::GetLength() const
//Returns the length of the current list
{
    return(length);
}

ParksNode Parks::GetNextPark()
//Gets the next park in the linked list
{
    ParksNode currentPark;
    currentPark.parkName = parkCurrentPos->parkName;
    currentPark.parkLocation = parkCurrentPos->parkLocation;
    currentPark.parkOpeningYear = parkCurrentPos->parkOpeningYear;
    currentPark.parkDescription = parkCurrentPos->parkDescription;
    currentPark.noTimesReferenced = parkCurrentPos->noTimesReferenced;
    parkCurrentPos = parkCurrentPos->parkLink;
    return(currentPark);
}


bool Parks::HasNext() const
//Checks to see if there is another park in the list
{
    return(parkCurrentPos!=NULL);
}

void Parks::Insert(string& pName, string& pLocation, string& pOpeningYear, 
string& pDescription, int& numberTimesReferenced)
//The insert method for the Parks Linked List class
{
    ParksPtr parkCurrPtr; //moving pointer
    ParksPtr parkPrevPtr; //trailing pointer
    ParksPtr parkNewNodePtr; //pointer to a new node

    parkNewNodePtr = new ParksNode;
    parkNewNodePtr->parkName = pName;
    parkNewNodePtr->parkLocation = pLocation;
    parkNewNodePtr->parkOpeningYear = pOpeningYear;
    parkNewNodePtr->parkDescription = pDescription;
    parkNewNodePtr->noTimesReferenced = numberTimesReferenced;

        parkCurrPtr = parkDataPtr;
        parkPrevPtr = NULL;
        while(parkCurrPtr != NULL && parkCurrPtr->parkName < pName)
        {
            parkPrevPtr = parkCurrPtr;
            parkCurrPtr = parkCurrPtr->parkLink;
        }
        //Inserting the new node
        parkNewNodePtr->parkLink = parkCurrPtr;
        if(parkPrevPtr == NULL)
        {
            parkDataPtr = parkNewNodePtr;
        }
        else
        {
            parkPrevPtr->parkLink = parkNewNodePtr;
        }
        if(parkCurrPtr == NULL)
        {
            parkLastPtr = parkNewNodePtr;
        }
    length++;
}

bool Parks::IsEmpty() const
//Checks to see if the list is empty
{
    return(parkDataPtr == NULL);
}

bool Parks::IsFull() const
//Checks to see if the list is full, will always return false because this 
is a linked list
{
    return(false);
}

bool Parks::IsThere(string pName) const
//Checks to see if an item is in the linked list
{
    ParksPtr parkCurrPtr = parkDataPtr; //Loop control pointer

    while(parkCurrPtr != NULL && parkCurrPtr->parkName != pName)
    {
        parkCurrPtr = parkCurrPtr->parkLink;
    }
    if(parkCurrPtr != NULL)
    {
        return(true);
    }
    else
    {
        return(false);
    }
}
```

updateLL.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstddef>
#include "parkLL.h"

void CloseFiles(ifstream& parkDataFile, ifstream& parkLookupFile, ofstream& 
parkOutputFile);
//This function closes all data files

void OpenFiles(string& parkDataFileName, string& parkLookupFileName, string& 
parkOutputFileName, ifstream& parkDataFile, ifstream& parkLookupFile, 
ofstream& parkOutputFile);
//This function opens all data files

int main()
{
    string parkDataFileName; //The variable for the data file for park info
    string parkLookupFileName; //The variable for the lookup file name
    string parkOutputFileName; //The variable for the output file name
    ifstream parkDataFile; //The variable for the park data input file
    ifstream parkLookupFile; //The variable for the park lookup file
    ofstream parkOutputFile; //The variable for the park output file
    string parkName2; //The variable for the park name
    string parkLocation2; //The variable for the park location
    string parkOpeningYear2; //The variable for the park opening year
    string parkDescription2; //The variable for the park description
    int noTimesReferenced2; //The variable for the number of times 
referenced
    string lookupChoice; //The variable for the information to look up
    string option; //The variable for the option of data output
    Parks currentPark; //The variable for the current park
    ParksPtr currentNode; //The variable for the current node

    cout << "Please enter the data file name: ";
    cin >> parkDataFileName;
    cout << "Please enter the lookup file name: ";
    cin >> parkLookupFileName;
    cout << "Please enter the output file name: ";
    cin >> parkOutputFileName;

    OpenFiles(parkDataFileName, parkLookupFileName, parkOutputFileName, 
parkDataFile, parkLookupFile, parkOutputFile);

    getline(parkDataFile, parkName2, '#'); //priming read for while loop
    while (parkDataFile)
    {
        getline(parkDataFile, parkLocation2, '#');
        getline(parkDataFile, parkOpeningYear2, '#');
        getline(parkDataFile, parkDescription2);
        noTimesReferenced2 = 0;
        currentPark.Insert(parkName2, parkLocation2, parkOpeningYear2, 
parkDescription2, noTimesReferenced2);
        getline(parkDataFile, parkName2, '#');
    }


    cout << endl;
    cout << "Outputting the info to file" << endl;

    getline(parkLookupFile, parkName2, '#');
    getline(parkLookupFile, lookupChoice);

    currentNode = new ParksNode;
    while(parkLookupFile)
    {
        if(currentPark.IsThere(parkName2))
        {
            if (lookupChoice == "Year")
            {   
                parkOutputFile << currentNode->parkName << " established in 
" << currentNode->parkOpeningYear << endl;
                currentNode->noTimesReferenced = currentNode-
>noTimesReferenced + 1;
            }

            else if (lookupChoice == "Description")
            {
                parkOutputFile << currentNode->parkName << " is " << 
currentNode->parkDescription << endl;
                currentNode->noTimesReferenced = currentNode-
>noTimesReferenced + 1;
            }

            else if (lookupChoice == "Location")
            {
                parkOutputFile << currentNode->parkName << " located near " 
 << currentNode->parkLocation << endl;
                currentNode->noTimesReferenced = currentNode-
>noTimesReferenced + 1;
            }
            else if (lookupChoice == "Remove")
            {
                currentPark.Delete(parkName2);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            parkOutputFile << "** " << parkName2 << " is not an available 
state park" << endl;
        }

        getline(parkLookupFile, parkName2, '#');
        getline(parkLookupFile, lookupChoice);
    }
    delete currentNode;

    parkOutputFile << "Summary (state park/ reference frequency)" << endl;

    while(currentPark.HasNext())
    {
        parkOutputFile << currentNode->parkName << " " << currentNode-
>noTimesReferenced;
    }


    CloseFiles(parkDataFile, parkLookupFile, parkOutputFile);

}

void CloseFiles(ifstream& parkDataFile, ifstream& parkLookupFile, ofstream& 
parkOutputFile)
{
    parkDataFile.close();
    parkLookupFile.close();
    parkOutputFile.close();
}

void OpenFiles(string& parkDataFileName, string& parkLookupFileName, string& 
parkOutputFileName, ifstream& parkDataFile, ifstream& parkLookupFile, 
ofstream& parkOutputFile)
{
    parkDataFile.open(parkDataFileName.c_str());
    parkLookupFile.open(parkLookupFileName.c_str());
    parkOutputFile.open(parkOutputFileName.c_str());
}
```

I apologize in advance for any syntax errors that may occur in the code as transferring the code is difficult. Please help me at your convenience. Thank you very much for any and all assistance with this matter.

Comment: Don't "transfer" the code. Instead try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then just use plain and simple copy-pasting.

Comment: `typedef ParksNode* ParksPtr;` pretty useless. Doesn’t make the code more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, however I am a student learning C++. I am trying to figure out what is causing my issue. I appreciate your comments, but could someone give me a little more detail on how to fix my error?

Comment: Use a debugger. That’s what everyone has to do.

Comment: I have debugged the program in its entirety, I am just unsure how to fill the currentNode variable from the linked list that is created for my class. I have attempted to use getters previously, but that gave me a segmentation fault. Do you have any suggestions as to how to transfer the data from my class into currentNode?

Comment: OT, but... 1) don't start your functions (main in this case) with a long list of variable declarations, try to declare (and possibly initialize) those variables just before their use and limit as much as possible their scopes. 2) Split the code in shorter (and with only one purpose) functions which are easier to think about, test and debug. 3) Since C++11 `std::ifstream` has a constructor accepting `std::string`. Moreover, its destructor is called when the end of its scope is reached (RAII): `{ std::ifstream file(FileName); if (!file) { /*Error opening*/ } /*else do something...*/ }`.

Comment: 4) [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) has a return value that should be checked.

Comment: The value of the getline function is checked, the problem comes in during the file output. The currentNode variable is empty, and I am unsure as to how to fill it. I have tried several methods to no avail. When the output file is created, it has statements with blank data entries where data should be. For example, "__ established in __" is all I see. It should have data before and after "established in".